# Flink diff file sink connections (Table api datastream api)

Tags: apache-flink

In [datastream api](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/connectors/datastream/file_sink/#row-encoded-formats) we have an argument **withInactivityInterval**, which can set our available interval until the file is closed.

But there is no such thing in the table api, and if our datastream to the table is suspended for a few seconds, the table api will close the file, and after a pause it will start a new one. Is there any way to avoid this?

And how we can set suffix in table api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have submitted a pr, if nothing else, it should be supported in version 1.15

https://github.com/apache/flink/pull/18359

Answer (score 1):

Confirmed the current implementation of table api， it really does not support setting inactivityInterval

I created a jira issue，then follow up, thanks for your feedback
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-25484